# Tornado - Poor performance for WebSocket game Server

Tags: python, performance, websocket, tornado

I read a lot about pros of Tornado Web Server, so I used it for creating simple WebSocket Game server..
Game is simple: Players can walk on map, by sending packet when trying to move to position, then server broadcast "Walk Packet" to all other players visible.
The problem is, Tornado is starting to having a huge problem when I am spawning 50-100 concurrent bot players (just sending 10 walk messages per second).

This is proffiler screen:
http://scr.hu/2g5f/1d43k

Is it my fault, or Tornado is not the best choice for server with big amount of small read/write packets?

tcp_nodelay is set to True.

Comment: I just tried diffrent approach: I changed sync interval to const: 20per second, and Iam packing all visible players data into one packet, then send it to player. Now CPU is not a problem, but Network traffic can be high in crowded areas (100 players - arount 4Mb/s).

Comment: Can you publish a simple Tornado websocket benchmark program?